# How to remove Move to OneDrive from Context Menu in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, context-menu, onedrive

Is there a way to remove Move to OneDrive from Context Menu in Windows 7

I can't find anything related to OneDrive in the following keys.

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFileSystemObjects\ShellEx
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers
```

[This page](https://winaero.com/blog/remove-onedrive-context-menu-windows-10/) and [this page](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/127208-add-remove-move-onedrive-context-menu-windows-10-a.html) provide a solution for Windows 10. But the solution does not change anything in Windows 7.

---

p.s. If you are curious, I am very much hoping to remove it because the keyboard shortcut overlaps with Rename, which is  inconvenient for productivity reasons.

Comment: See this utility....https://www.lopesoft.com/index.php/en/products/filemenutools